# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, multisite

first time posting here and I hope you can assist please :-)

Currently running a WP multisite environment (none of the sites are live yet) of which there are currently six (6).

Hadn't logged in for some time and on attempting to do so yesterday I cannot access network admin in order to update the network/plugins etc since the recent WP 6.0.2 update.  Can get to the dashboards for only four of the six sites.

Tried disabling the plugins to see if that allowed access but to no avail.

**1.** Below is the error page on trying to login in to /wp-admin for the network:

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php:2407 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): wp_global_styles_render_svg_filters('') #1 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/general-template.php(3074): do_action('wp_body_open') #4 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/themes/creativeily/functions.php(435): wp_body_open() #5 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-settings.php(566): include('/homepages/24/d...') #6 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-config.php(107): require_once('/homepages/24/d...') #7 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/homepages/24/d...') #8 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/homepages/24/d...') #9 /homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/homepages/24/d...') #10 {main} thrown in **/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php** on line **2407**

There has been a critical error on this website.

**2.** And this is the code on trying to access one of the other sites:

**Warning:** session_id(): Cannot change session id when session is active in **/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woozone/aa-framework/framework.class.php** on line **1034**

**Warning:** require(/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/themes/xstore/theme/widgets-import.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/et-core-plugin/inc/import.php** on line **32**

**Fatal error:** require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/themes/xstore/theme/widgets-import.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.4') in **/homepages/24/d379594114/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/et-core-plugin/inc/import.php** on line **32**

There has been a critical error on this website.

---

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated please.
Many thanks,
Caz

Comment: Hi all.  I've managed to successfully gain access and update my network - phew!

Comment: I did this via SFTP, in /wp-content/themes/ I renamed the directory of the currently active theme. This, apparently, forced the default theme to activate and so it let me in - YAY!  
Looks like my issue was theme related, but I hope this helps someone else in the future.
Will come back with a further update if I discover anything else worth reporting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this issue was to deactivate the plugin associated with the error. In my case, it was the Bluehost management plugin.